# MongoDB addShard doesn't add a new shard to the cluster

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB cluster of 2 nodes. The 2 nodes are hosting each:

- one config server
- one shard server
- one mongos instance

When I connect to the machine 1 on a mongos and execute:

> sh.status()

```
I can see in the sections shards:

shards
[
  {
    _id: 'replicaSetShardServer1',
    host: 'replicaSetShardServer1/machine1:port',
    state: 1,
    topologyTime: Timestamp({ t: 1669040465, i: 2 })
  }
]
```

But I can't see the machine 2.

So I follow the procedure to add the machine 2 to the replica set.

1. Connect on the mongos instance
2. Execute

> sh.addShard("replicaSetShardServer1/machine2:port

It returns :

```
{
  shardAdded: 'replicaSetShardServer1',
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1675869627, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("323787680faa463455c0aea72d3d9c722575dfda", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("7168472318795055129")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1675869627, i: 1 })
}
```

Then I execute the sh.status() again but I still have one shard only (the same as above) indicated in the shard section, therefor I assume the shard isn't taking into consideration.

Am I doing something wrong ?

The result of the command db.adminCommand("getShardMap").map is

```
{
  replicaSetShardServer1: 'replicaSetShardServer1/machine1:27018',
  config: 'replicaSetConfigServer1/machine1:27019,machine2:27019'
}
```

Comment: What do you get from `db.adminCommand("getShardMap").map`? (to be run at `mongos`)

Comment: Also, why are you reusing the replica set name `replicaSetShardServer1`?

Comment: This seems more like a database administration question than a programming question.  You might get better response from dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Joe There is a migration option to dba.stackexchange.com in the close reason. We can use that to migrate the question.

Comment: @user20042973 Am I supposed to use a different one ? For me, the goal is to add a machine with the same replica set shard. As the documentation suggest it.

Comment: Again, what do you get from `db.adminCommand("getShardMap").map` with an answer we may see the problem.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, just edited the post. I basically have the same info as sh.status().

Comment: You want to add another **shard**, thus the share name must be different to any existing shard. Should be `sh.addShard("replicaSetShardServer2/machine2:port`

Comment: You write "The 2 nodes are hosting each: one shard server" According to your output the 2nd node does not host any shard server.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes I think I don't really understand what are shard and replication set. What I wanted to do is, "adding a member to the replication set." The thing that is a bit confusing is that when I had a server in the replication set, it is display in this "shard" section.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit And yet it did host a shard server, this node was just node added to the resplication set hence why it wasn't displayed in those result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced 2 issues:

1. I had to use the rs.add("replicationSet/node2:27018") to add the node to the replication set.
2. I had to add a user for the shard server replication set in order to use the rs.add("replicationSet/node2:27018")

For the first point, the missing part of the equation was that I had to firstly add the shard server to the replica set shard server and then call add shard. No error was prompted to the response of the addShard() call.

For the second point, in a mongoDB sharded cluster, there is 2 kind of users.
One that is created through the mongos and used to deal with data and collection operation (query a collection, write to it etc..).

And there is the shard local users, those are created connecting directly to a mongod instance. Those are used for administrative tasks.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-users/#sharded-cluster-users

Comment: Maybe have a look at this picture to get a better view: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharded-cluster-components/#number-of-mongos-and-distribution or this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/278634/when-and-how-to-create-users-in-a-mongodb-sharded-cluster